# How to access typescpirt empty object properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript

my code is like this

type.js

```
export interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

I am using react

Coponent.tsx

```
const [state,setState] = useState<User|{}>({});

const isValid = () =>{
 const clone = { ...state};
 
 const name:string = clone.name //<= error

}
```

i tried this

```
 const name:string = clone?.name
```

Any good solutions?

Comment: You need to initialise `name` first. the object property doesn't exist at the point that you are assigning it to the name variable

Answer (score 1):

`User | {}` does not mean 'a possibly empty User object.' It means this type is either an object of type `User` or an empty object. In your React code, you've set the `state` variable to be an empty object, which will never have the `name` or `age` properties.

From the code you've shared, it's hard to deduce what you're trying to accomplish. But depending on what you're trying to do, you could try something like this:

```
const Component = () => {
  // forget an empty object, use null or undefined (the below expression will set state to undefined)
  const [state, setState] = useState<User | undefined>();

  const isValid = (): boolean => {
    if (!state) {
      return false;
    }
    // now that we know state is not null or undefined, we know it's of type `User`! We can now clone our state for whatever we're trying to do
    const clone = { ...state};
 
    const name:string = clone.name //<= should no longer error
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: @CollinD fair, I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [state, setState] = useState<User | undefined>();

  const isValid = () => {
    if (!state) {
      return false;
    }

    // do validate
    const clone = { ...state };
    const name: string = clone.name;
  };
```

Comment: Hey licky! Could you add a few words of explanation why this is a solution?

Comment: `undefined` is means nothing , so use `User | undefined` is means the state will be a User object or nothing.  `if(! state){return false;}` can make sure state not a undefined in below code scope, so we can use state.name directly. And I think `const clone = {...state} `can be omited.

Answer (score -2):

Please try with this.

```js
const {name} = clone;
```

Comment: `const { name } = clone;` is the same as `const name = clone.name;`, which is what is throwing the error.